# Easiest way to test how much time an operation takes in Qt

Tags: c++, performance, qt

I am with Qt 4.8, and try to be cross platform (at least on linux and mac).

I need to visualize in the gui how much times an operation takes. I have tried with:

```
QTime t;
t.start();
functionCall();
qDebug() << t.elapsed() << "ms";
```

But I've read that it is not reliable. Some alternatives?

Sorry, no C++0x

Comment: This was asked before here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244646/qt-fast-way-to-measure-time However, the accepted and most voted for answer there is wrong. Qt doesn't provide a way to get CPU process time. You can try `<ctime>`, but it's usually not that accurate. See my answer to that question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13003327/856199

Comment: What sort of precision do you need (i.e. roughly how long do the things you're measuring last)? ("Not reliable" sounds strange. Might not be accurate enough, but that's a different issue.)

Comment: @Mat The main problem here is that QTime doesn't measure CPU time consumed by your code. It measures actual real time, even if your code isn't running at all.

Comment: @NikosC.: well of the OP wants CPU time rather than wall-clock, that's a pretty big piece of information missing in the question.

Comment: what is most used in menchmarking? cpu time?

Comment: Usually you need wall clock time when benchmarking other applications, and CPU time when profiling your own code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not reliable and not very accurate. Use [QElapsedTimer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qelapsedtimer.html) instead.

Of course, both QTime and QElapsedTimer measure wall clock time. You need QtTest and QBENCHMARK [in order to get other measures](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qttestlib/qtest-overview.html#benchmarking-options) (callgrind, CPU tick counters, etc.), see also the [QTest::setBenchmarkResult](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qttestlib/qtest.html#setBenchmarkResult) function.

Comment: I thought `QBENCHMARK` could be used only on unit test, I need it in the application

Comment: You can use any `QtTest` features in your application as long as you link with `QtTest` library.

Comment: Be careful with `QElapsedTimer`. It seems bugged right now (Qt 5.6) -- I can use `objectName.start()` and `objectName.elapsed()`, but intellisense isn't popping those up, only static members. They do work, though. It seems to happen in definition files, not headers.