# Time of execution in Qt Creator for C++

Tags: c++, qt-creator

How do I modify the .pro file in a C++ project to print the time of execution of a particular code? I use Qt Creator as a general C++ IDE in Ubuntu 13.04.

In terminal, I would use

```
time ./a.out
```

My current .pro file is

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x
```

Comment: Why do you think it should be done in a pro file?

Comment: I thought the pro file is used to enter the commands we want to be executed while compiling the code. Sorry about that.

Comment: While compiling, yes. But your question is about _execution_ time. However, now that I'm reading it again, I have no idea what time you want to measure.

Comment: I use c++ for project Euler and would like to measure the execution times for various problems

Answer (score 3):

Why not trying the QBENCHMARK? As the code below shows, you can insert the code you want to measure inside a QBENCHMARK macro. [Reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtest-overview.html#creating-a-benchmark)

```
class MyFirstBenchmark: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
private slots:
    void myFirstBenchmark()
    {
        QString string1;
        QString string2;
        QBENCHMARK {
            string1.localeAwareCompare(string2);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: My question was actually asked before at http://stackoverflow.com/q/244646/2802439 and there are several comments regarding the same.
Thanks for replying anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Expending the previous answers, here is a macro that does everything for you.

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QElapsedTimer>
#define CONCAT_(x,y) x##y
#define CONCAT(x,y) CONCAT_(x,y)

#define CHECKTIME(x)  \
    QElapsedTimer CONCAT(sb_, __LINE__); \
    CONCAT(sb_, __LINE__).start(); \
    x \
    qDebug() << __FUNCTION__ << ":" << __LINE__ << " Elapsed time: " <<  CONCAT(sb_, __LINE__).elapsed() << " ms.";
```

And then you can simple use as:

```
CHECKTIME(
    // any code
    for (int i=0; i<1000; i++)
    {
       timeConsumingFunc();
    }
)
```

In your case, if you want the entire program execution time, you can simply include the whole content of main on that macro. Need to be careful about the event loop i suppose.

output:

> onSpeedChanged : 102  Elapsed time:  2  ms.