# Qt unit tests: time of execution

Tags: qt, unit-testing, qt-creator

I'm using unit testing framework from qt library.

And looking for a feature -how much time each test takes independently of passed/failed result.

Is it possible?

Comment: You might use QTimer.

Comment: See this previous question: [Get elapsed time in Qt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244646/get-elapsed-time-in-qt)

Answer (score 1):

There is no automatic way to report all test times, but Qt Test module has a [benchmarking feature](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtest-overview.html#creating-a-benchmark) that you can wrap each test in.

```
class MyFirstBenchmark: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
private slots:
    void myFirstBenchmark()
    {
        QString string1;
        QString string2;
        QBENCHMARK {
            string1.localeAwareCompare(string2);
        }
    }
};
```